# UISlider not progressing smoothly

Tags: ios, swift3, uislider

I have two UIViewControllers and each one has a `UISlider`. One slider tracks the progress of an audio file playing from `AVPlayer` the other viewcontroller slider tracks the progress of an audio file playing from `AVAudioPlayer`. The slider responding to `AVPlayer` animates perfectly smooth while the animation for the slider responding to `AVAudioPlayer` is not smooth. The sliders are set up exactly the same except for how I obtain the current time of each player as shown below:

```
//AVPlayer slider

func trackAudio() {
    let currentTime = self.newPlayer!.currentTime()
    let currentTimeInSeconds = CMTimeGetSeconds(currentTime)
    slider.setValue(Float(currentTimeInSeconds), animated: true)
}        


//AVAudioPlayer Slider

func trackAudio() {
    let currentTime = self.player!.currentTime
    slider.setValue(Float(currentTime), animated: true)
}

func playPressed(){

    player!.play()
    updater = CADisplayLink(target: self, selector: #selector(RecordController.trackAudio))
    updater.add(to: RunLoop.current, forMode: RunLoopMode.commonModes)
}
```

Comment: How are you triggering your two trackAudio methods? With timers? If so, are they set up with the same interval?

Comment: @DuncanC I use `CADisplayLink`. Updated answer with the code.

Comment: Just figured it out. So this view controller has two purposes: record and play. Recording precedes playing and involves an animation that uses `CADisplayLink`. Once recording stops and I play the recording I'm using `CADisplayLink` again to update the slider. I removed the CADisplayLink from the recording animation and the slider works perfectly. Now i have to figure out how to get them to work together.

Answer (score 0):

The reason for the non-smooth UISlider was because i had two CADisplayLink's in the same view controller.

I initially had the following:

```
var displayLink: CADisplayLink?  // for recording animation
var updater: CADisplayLink?      // for updating slider


func record() {
     let displayLink = CADisplayLink(target: self, selector:#selector(RecordController.updateMeters))
     displayLink.add(to: RunLoop.current, forMode: RunLoopMode.commonModes)
}

func play() {
    let updater = CADisplayLink(target: self, selector: #selector(RecordController.trackAudio))
    updater.add(to: RunLoop.current, forMode: RunLoopMode.commonModes)
}
```

I got it to work by doing:

```
func record() {
     self.displayLink = CADisplayLink(target: self, selector:#selector(RecordController.updateMeters))
     self.displayLink.add(to: RunLoop.current, forMode: RunLoopMode.commonModes)
}

func play() {
    self.displayLink = CADisplayLink(target: self, selector: #selector(RecordController.trackAudio))
    self.displayLink.add(to: RunLoop.current, forMode: RunLoopMode.commonModes)
}
```